# Want to use jquery SlickGrid in gwt

Tags: jquery, gwt, slickgrid

I want to use jquery SlickGrid in gwt. Has anybody tried this ? Currently silkgrid is very popular. But before I start on it, if anyone used it already, please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GWT is a wrapper library. There is a [`gwt-jquery`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jquery/) - A GWT library that wraps the existing jQuery , jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile javascript libraries,  to use `jQuery` with GWT.

I think GWT-Wrapper is still not developed for `SlickGrid`. This [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid) somewhat confirm on the same.